# What actions should be taken after water heater supply pipe damage?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

Water pipe to water heater burst after 3,5 quake. Do we turn off the water heater and the water or just turn water heater to pilot?

Comment: I'd turn off the gas main ASAP until you're sure there are no gas leaks!

Answer (score 1):

Turn off water supply to water heater, turn off (not pilot) gas to water heater. If the cold water shutoff to the heater is beyond the break, turn off the main water supply valve.